# MVC update Dropdownlistfor with jquery

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a Dropdownlistfor connected to my model. When the page is loaded the model is empty, but I have a button on the page that updates the model. My problem is that my dropdownlist doesn't update.

Markup:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddlRaces", new SelectList(ViewBag.Races, "RaceId", "Name"))
<input type="button" id="btnChangeRace" class="btnGo" value=" " />

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Timers, new SelectList(Model.Timers, "TimerId", "StartTime"), "Velg timer:")
```

Script:

```
btnChangeRace.click(function () {
    url = "/TimeMerger/GetTimers/?raceId=" + ddlRaces.val();
    $.get(url);
});
```

Codebehind:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetTimers(int raceId)
{
    var timeMergeModel = new TimeMergerModel();
    timeMergeModel.Timers = TimerModel.GetTimers(raceId);
    return View(timeMergeModel);
}
```

Comment: Show us the declaration of the btnChangeRace and ddlRaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.get(url);
```

Here you are sending an AJAX request but you are doing nothing in the success callback so nothing will update. There is not even a success callback. So you need to define a success callback:

```
$.get(url, function(result) {
    // result here will represent the value returned by the server
    // which in your case is HTML. So here you might need to update 
    // the relevant portion of your page.
});
```

Also your `DropDownListFor` definition is wrong. You are using the same model variable as first and second argument (Model.Timers). The first first argument of this helper should be a scalar property to which you are binding and not a list. It should be:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    m => m.SelectedTimerValue, 
    new SelectList(Model.Timers, "TimerId", "StartTime"), 
    "Velg timer:"
)
```

where `SelectedTimerValue` would be a property on your view model that will hold the selected value. Also why you are using `DropDownList` instead of `DropDownListFor` for the first drop down? The whole idea of a view model is that it will contain all the necessary information so that the view would simply display it.